# Capitalize the First Letter of my item, oracle apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have an apex page item P10_NAME here i need to enter only capital letter , it should not allow users to enter lower case, while entering the data i need to restrict instead of checking while save the record.

How to perform this

Eg:
P10_NAME : hjhjhj   --- it should not allow lower case

P10_NAME : ASDASD  ---- allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Apex 20.2 (don't have 5.x any more so I can't check); it lets you use appropriate settings which take care about letter case:

[image]

---

If your Apex version doesn't support it, then navigate to "Advanced" set of properties and put this into **Custom Attributes**:

```
style="text-transform:uppercase"
```

Comment: style="text-transform:uppercase" this is only convert uppercase in apex form only, but records saved in lower case also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '.u-textUpper', function() {
    var i = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
    $(i).val($(i).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

use the above javascript code, it will change the upper case,

you just assign the class in `u-textUpper`

[image]